# Get previous element in a scope

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm struggling with an issue and would like your advice please.
I've set up a code that moves up or down some blocks

Problem is, the block i'm trying to move is a position -1. So everyone works fine at first click. But when I try to move it again, instead of doing the job from the newly acquired position, it takes the one that is at -1 again. And since the first one I moved is now 0, it will never do the work depending on the block that has been moved.
Could anyone help me please ? This is kinda driving me crazy.

```
$scope.move = (origin, destination, item, position, new_position, is_a_theme) ->
    console.log($scope)
    console.log($scope.item)

    temp = $scope.$ctrl.themes[destination]
    $scope.$ctrl.themes[destination] = $scope.$ctrl.themes[origin]
    $scope.$ctrl.themes[origin] = temp


  $scope.moveUp = (position) ->
    if $scope.item.active = true & is_a_theme = true
      $scope.move($scope.item.position - 1, $scope.item.position - 2)

  $scope.moveDown = (position) ->
    if $scope.item.active = true & is_a_theme = true
      $scope.move($scope.item.position - 1, $scope.item.position)
```

Comment: I think it is better to use 0 based position instead of doing -1 and -2

Comment: I've tried that too. For some reason, the first element would rather start at -1 instead of 0, which is one of the main reasons i'm having trouble get through.

Comment: What I had in mind was to handle both blocks when a change is done. When I click the down button, it goes from -1 to 0 and the one that was at 0 goes to -1. But the code doesn't seem right.
$scope.move($scope.item.position - 1, $scope.item.position) && ($scope.item.position, $scope.item.position - 1)
But an error "unexpected ," occurs.

Comment: oh ok, you shouldn't keep a position attr on the item itself, you should always use its index in the array, or you'll have to update them everytime

Comment: you can easily find the index by using `indexOf`

Comment: Sorry for the quite stupid question i'm about to ask but what would that look like into the code ? I've been into the indexOf documentation and quite don't know how to implement it correctly. I'm still new to this language. Sorry again for the disturbance.

Answer (score 0):

While trying out I found that using `findIndex` is more straight forward.

Example code:

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', TestController);

function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'A'},
    {name: 'B'},
    {name: 'C'},
    {name: 'D'}
  ]
  
  $scope.select = function(item) {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(i) {
      i.active = (i == item);
    });
  }
  
  $scope.up = function() {
    var selectedIndex = $scope.items.findIndex(function(i) {
      return i.active;
    });
    
    swap(selectedIndex, selectedIndex - 1);
  }
  
  $scope.down = function() {
    var selectedIndex = $scope.items.findIndex(function(i) {
      return i.active;
    });
    
    swap(selectedIndex, selectedIndex + 1);
  }
  
  function swap(a, b) {
    if (a < 0 || b < 0 || a >= $scope.items.length || b >= $scope.items.length) {
      return;
    }
    
    var tmp = $scope.items[a];
    $scope.items[a] = $scope.items[b];
    $scope.items[b] = tmp;
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div class='item'
       ng-repeat='item in items' 
       ng-class='{active: item.active}'
       ng-click='select(item)'>
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type='button' ng-click='up()'>up</button>
  <button type='button' ng-click='down()'>down</button>
</div>
```